# How to cleanly (physically) seperate the domain layer from spring data code?

Tags: domain-driven-design, spring-data, ddd-repositories

In my DDD-by-the-book application, I have a repository definition like this in my domain layer:

```
public interface CustomerRepository {
    Customer findById(long id);
    ...
}
```

The database integration layer contains the implementation of this interface, like this:

```
public class CustomerDao implements CustomerRepository {
    public Customer findById(long id) {
        // access EntityManager or JDBCTemplates or ...
    }
}
```

There is a module for each layer, and the database module depends on domain and all integration libraries (e.g. hibernate), while the domain module depends on anything. So we have clean seperation of concerns and no "technical" dependencies of the domain, as DDD proposes. As a consequence, I can switch from database to in-memory persistency by creating an appropriate repository implementation. The implementation that is used is configured in my application layer.

Implementing repositories for database access is awful, and is not necessary any more as we have Spring Data around. To use spring data, I have to define a repository like this.

```
public interface CustomerRepository implements Repository<Customer, Long> {
    ....
```

That means, as the repository interface definition is in my domain layer, I now have a dependency of my domain layer to a "technical" library. When switching to the in-memory implementation, I will also have the spring-data classes in my application. I think, this smells a bit.

How do you think about it? How do you handle this? Is it possible to use spring data and NOT have a dependency from my domain layer?

thx

(BTW: My business object are JPA annotated, therefore my domain module has a dependency to javax.persistence. But I can live with this, mainly because javax.persistence only contains annotations and no implementations. So this is rather a "logical" than a "technical" dependency. I suppose a dependency to a spring-data-annotation module would smell less.)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with sprint-data but couldn't you say something like CustomerDae implements CustomerRepository, Repository<Customer, Long>

Comment: Because `Repository<Customer, Long>` is the interface from Spring Data and author does not want his domain interface depend on it directly

Comment: It's not a problem, if the CustomerDao depends on the Spring Data Repository, because the Dao is the implementation of the repository interface, and is inside the integration layer. But to use Spring Data directly, the repository interface would extend the Spring Data Repository.

Answer (score 6):

Recently I have faced the same challange when working on a project using Spring Data and following the Onion architecture. Below is my recipe:

1. define CustomerRepository (in your domain layer) without references to Spring Data:

   ```
   public interface CustomerRepository {
     Customer findById(long id);
     // ..
   }
   ```
2. define CustomerDao in your data access layer, which has a dependency to Spring Data:

   ```
   public CustomerDao implements Repository<Customer, Long> { }
   ```
3. define an implementation of domain CustomerRepository which will delegate all its calls to CustomerSpringDataRepository and which will have a CustomerDao instance injected by Spring:

   ```
   public class CustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerRepository {
      @Autowired private CustomerDao dao;

      public Customer findById(long id) { return doa.findById(id); }
   }
   ```
4. inject CustomerRepository in your domain layer

With such approach:

- your domain layer does not have a dependency to Spring Data, only the data access layer has a dependency to Spring Data
- your domain does not depend on the data access layer, which means no infrastructure (such as Spring Data) classes show up in the domain

I have created [a sample project using Spring Data and the Onion architecture](https://github.com/adko-pl/springboot-with-spring_data-and-onion_architecture) following the above approach.

Answer (score 1):

Inject Spring Data repository into your domain repository , then your domain repository interface will not depend on the "technical" library anymore.

```
public interface CustomerSprignDataRepository implements Repository<Customer, Long> {

}
```

---

```
public class CustomerDao implements CustomerRepository {

      @Inject
      private CustomerSprignDataRepository customerSprignDataRepository;

      public Customer findById(long id) {
          // access EntityManager or JDBCTemplates or Spring Data Repository
      }
}
```

Comment: If you inject Spring Data repository, which uses the Spring data classes/interfaces (Repository), into your domain then your domain must have a dependency to Spring Data.

Comment: @adam, what are the differences between your suggestion and mine? Both are injecting a spring data repository into the doman repository implemention,i cannot see there are any fundanmental differences except both use different names to name the repositories.Also,the domain will depend on the domain repository interface only but not its implementation,hence it will not depend on spring data dependency

Comment: "Inject Spring Data repository" - you mean `CustomerDao` or `CustomerSpringDataRepository`?

Comment: @adam, I think its name already gives you the answer.  "Spring Data repository" means [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) . So it is Customer**SpringDataRepository**  .

Comment: Ok, so to compile `CustomerSpringDataRepository`, which extends Spring Data's `Repository` (BTW in your code snippet there is an error) you need Spring Data, so in order to be able to inject `CustomerSpringDataRepository` into your domain layer you need a dependency to Spring Data, something that the question author does want.

Comment: @AdamSiemion : Domain uses `CustomerRepository` directly , which is just an interface and is free from any Spring Data dependencies. . `CustomerSpringDataRepository` will never inject into the domain , it is injected into the `CustomerDao`.Both `CustomerSpringDataRepository` and `CustomerDao` are inside author 's database integration layer .Again , I really can't see what are the fundamental differences  between your suggestion and mine .

Comment: Yes, it is the same approach. I guess the first sentence misled me "Inject Spring Data repository into your domain repository", from that a made a incorrect assumption that you are suggesting to inject Spring Data repos into the domain. Mea culpa, +1.